# Displaying JPanel to JFrame another class

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a main JFrame and three java class that contains different pie charts and these piechart are in panel. I want to call the three pie classes in main jframe. How can l do that?[image]

// I have three of these Chart classes creating different charts inside panels

```
public class PiePanel extends Observer {

Singleton connCC = Singleton.getInstance();
Connection con = null;
Statement stm = null;

PiePanel(Subject s) {
panel = new JPanel();
sub = s;
}

@Override
public void update() {
try {
    con = connCC.getDBconnection();
    stm = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("Select pet_name as pet,     count(pet_ID) AS 'count' from Pet group by pet_name");
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    while (rs.next()) {
        dataset.setValue(rs.getString("pet"), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("count")));
    }

    JFreeChart pieChart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Header", dataset, true, true, false);
    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) pieChart.getPlot();
    plot.setSimpleLabels(true);

    PieSectionLabelGenerator gen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator(
            "{0}: {1} ({2})", new DecimalFormat("0"), new DecimalFormat("0%"));
    plot.setLabelGenerator(gen);

    panel.add(new ChartPanel(pieChart) {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(335, 235);
        }
    });

    panel.validate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

}

//below is a class that puts all the panels inside a list

```
 public class Subject {
private List<Observer> panel = new ArrayList<Observer>();
public Subject(){
   panel.add(new BarPanel(this));
   panel.add(new AreaPanel(this));
   panel.add(new PiePanel(this));
}
public List<Observer> getChart(){
      return panel;
}
```

}

//main

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Subject s = new Subject();

    while (true) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input value:");
        if ("d".equals(input) || "w".equals(input)) {
            try {
                //String value = Integer.parseInt(input);
                s.setState(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Input!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Now i want to pass this list in another JFrame class just as in the picture.

Comment: Use setters in the JFrame class for each of the Pie objects. You can do `this.add(pie)` from that method

Comment: @Meli What exactly is your question? Are you asking how to pass the ***same instance*** of the list into different classes, such that all classes are ***sharing*** the same data?

Comment: Just want to pass the instance of the list in the JFrame class

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're adding three components in a default fashion to a container that uses BorderLayout, and this results in each added component in the BorderLayout.CENTER covering all the other components added previously. If you want to display three components you can:

- Use BorderLayout constants to add the components to different locations within the BorderLayout-using container, or
- use a different layout, here perhaps a GridLayout(3, 1), or
- if you want a more complex GUI that shows more components, then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager.

  - For example, if you want to display the pie charts to the side for instance, then I'd put them into a JPanel that uses a GridLayout, and then add that GridLayout using JPanel to the BorderLayout-using main GUI in the BorderLayout.LINE_END position, or whatever location you desire.

If on the other hand your goal is to swap out one JPanel for another in response to an event, then use a CardLayout to allow easy and efficient swapping of components.

Comment: Thanks for reply, no i am not going to swap i just need to display pie charts in my main frame.

Comment: @Meli: then use a more appropriate layout manager. If you want to display the pie charts to the side for instance, then I'd put them into a JPanel that uses a GridLayout, and then add that GridLayout using JPanel to the BorderLayout-using main GUI in the BorderLayout.LINE_END position, or whatever location you desire.

Comment: I made some changes in my question to make it more clear. Thanks again

Comment: @Meli: My answer is still valid. Do you still have a question or have another question about this answer?

Comment: Yes. I have putted these three classes of panels inside a list but im still not clear on how to pass it to the frame?

Comment: @Meli: then you need to post more information and code, preferably a [mcve]. Please check this link to see how to use this valuable tool.

Comment: @Meli: and just what do you mean by, `"...not clear on how to pass it to the frame?"`. What's wrong with what your demo code above currently does? Again, you may wish to flesh out your question a bit by providing any details and code necessary for us to fully understand your problem.

Comment: I added some of the classes, you may have a look! Thanks.

Comment: @Meli: Do you have [duplicate identities for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671508/passing-a-list-of-panels-in-a-jframe-class-java#35671508)? Please delete the duplicate question, and **again** please create and post a *valid* [mcve], one that is small yet is **compilable and runnable** for us. Otherwise we're all just spinning our wheels.

Comment: @Meli: Your current code does not compile *for us*, has no main method and so does not run, and so we're stuck.

Comment: I added the main method thats how i run now separately, but I want now to place these three charts inside the jFrame class. How can i pass these panels all in one JFrame(note I have a drag and drop JFrame).

Comment: @Meli: and again, we cannot compile nor run any of this code. For one it contains too many outside dependencies that we have no access to such as database code (get rid of it from your MCVE), and classes, such as BarPanel, AreaPanel, Singleton. I'm not asking you to add all of these classes, but rather to simplify your code so that we can compile and run it unmodified, so that it has no database dependence, and so that it's small, small enough to post here in its entirety. Have you read the [mcve] protocol? If not, please have a critical look at it.